# How can I show that the stopping time $T=\min\{n\geq 0: S_n=1\}<\infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stopping-times

> Let be consider random variables $X_i$ which are independent and such that $\Bbb{P}(X_i=1)=1-2^{-i}$ and $\Bbb{P}(X_i=1-2^i)=2^{-i}$. Then define $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $T=\min\{n\geq 0: S_n=1\}$.

I want to check that $T<\infty $ a.s.

I have already remarked that $S_n$ is a martingale.
My idea was to show that $\Bbb{P}(T=\infty)=0$. Then $$\Bbb{P}(T=\infty)=\Bbb{P}(\min\{n\geq 0: S_n=1\}=\infty)=\Bbb{P}(S_n\neq 1~\forall n)=1-\Bbb{P}(\exists~ n~: S_n=1)$$Now I somehow wanted to rewrite the event that for one $n$, $S_n=1$. but I don't managed to do it, is there a trick?

Comment: It's worth noting that $T<\infty$ a.s. is not the same as $T$ being bounded.  There are some theorems that only apply to bounded stopping times that don't apply if the stopping time is just finite a.s.

Comment: @user6247850 I see thanks I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(X_n \neq 1)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}2^{-n}<\infty$$
So by Borel-Cantelli I $P(X_n\neq 1\textrm{ i.o.})=0$. So in particular
$$P\bigg(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{k\geq n}\{X_k=1\}\bigg)=1$$
I.e. for a.a. $\omega \in \Omega$, $\exists n(\omega)$ s.t. $\forall k\geq n(\omega)$, $X_k(\omega)=1$. So $S_n$ eventually 'shots up' to infinity, almost surely, and reaches any positive integer. So $P(T<\infty)=1$.

Comment: Sorry could you explain the last part again I can follow you till the point where you say that $\Bbb{P}(\limsup_n X_n=1)=1$ but I don't see how you conclude. Could you explain this a bit in more detail?

Comment: For almost all $\omega$, there exists a point in time $N(\omega)$ after which $X_n=1$ for all $n$ afterwards. This means that almost surely $S_n(\omega)$ eventually increases by $1$ at each step indefinitely, going to $+\infty$ in the limit.

Comment: But why do I know $S_n=1$ in finite time since $S_n$ increases by $1$ at each step?

Comment: @user123234 Note that by definition $P(S_n\textrm{ is finite for all }n)=1$. Our result yields $P(X_n=1\textrm{ eventually})=1$. Since $\{\lim_n S_n=\infty\}\supseteq \{S_n\textrm{ is finite for all }n\}\cap \{X_n=1\textrm{ eventually}\}$ we get
$$P(\lim_n S_n \neq \infty)\leq P(S_n\textrm{ is not finite for some }n)+P(X_n\neq 1\textrm{ i.o.})=0$$

Comment: @user123234 Where did you see $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n X_n = 1)=1$ in the argument, anyway?

Comment: **@user123234:** If $X_1=1$ then $T=1$. Otherwise $S_1=-1<0$. In this case, because $X_k=1$ for all large $k$, a.s., you have $S_n>1$ eventually, and then $S_m=1$ for some $m\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$.